# IContainer.findMember(IPath arg0) not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface, eclipse-pde

I am trying to make an eclipse plugin for creation of a file, I was able to get some reference from the template code that is there in eclipse. however, when I use `findMember` function to check if the package exists, It is returning null. I am sure that the folder structure is present in the directory.
I am really new to eclipse plugin development and any help would be really appreciated.

Adding code and folder structure below

```java
String locationString="/demo_package";
IPath path = new Path(locationString);
IResource container = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(path);
```

Folder Structure:
[image: Folder Structure picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findMember` will only return things created using the Eclipse APIs, it will not find a plain folder you created some other way unless you do a `IResource.refreshLocal`.

In any case only projects can be at the top level of a workspace.

If your plugin wants to store data it should be in the plug-in "state location" returned by `Platform.getStateLocation` which is in the workspace metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How do I check if a particular package exists or not? this is basically for the file creation part, I want to check if the package exists, if it exists , I will create the file in that package.

Comment: What do mean by "package"?  A Java package would be in a source directory in a Java project. Working out the location for a Java package in a project requires quite a lot of knowledge about Eclipse JDT structures. I think you need to be much clearer about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand. So I want to achieve something like this with my eclipse plugin. I am getting a package location and a project name from the user, I want to see if that package location exists in the source directory of the project or not, If it exists I want to create some file with some template code in that package of that particular project. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: The answer helped. Thanks!